# How to access execution date in Airflow for operators other than python or bash?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I am using Bigquery_to_gcs operator in airflow. I want to save the tables in folder with execution start date as name of folder. Since the tasks run overnight, datetime.today() sometimes gives next day as execution start date. How can I access dag execution start date in place of datetime.today(), so that all tables get stored in folder with execution start date as folder name.

```
BQ_to_GCS=bigquery_to_gcs.BigQueryToGCSOperator(task_id="xyz",
 source_project_dataset_table="p.t1",
 destination_cloud_storage_uris=[f'gs://bucket/{datetime.today()}/tablename'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply Jinja templating in the given path, which means code between double curly braces is evaluated at runtime. For example:

```py
destination_cloud_storage_uris=['gs://bucket/{{ ds }}/tablename']
```

*(note: no f-string)*

In this example, `ds` is a variable available in Airflow at runtime, which represents the start date of the interval, formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD`, e.g. `2021-01-01`. So the full path is evaluated at runtime as `'gs://bucket/2021-01-01/tablename'`.

Airflow provides several variables at runtime which you can use for templating, see the full list here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html.

Comment: Thanks it worked. But on documentation its written "The DAG run’s logical date, and values derived from it, such as ds and ts, should not be considered unique in a DAG. Use run_id instead."

Comment: Correct. Indeed use `run_id` if you require unique folders. Variables such as `ds` are typically used for partitioned data, so you'd e.g. create one folder per day.